# Extract number from string in MSBuild

Tags: regex, msbuild, numbers

I would like to extract the number from a string in MSBuild.

How can I do that using the built in tasks or the MSBuild.Community.Tasks? (RegexMatch might do, but how?)

Example: I have the string

```
agent0076
```

and I would like to get out the number, without the leading zeros:

```
76
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Using MSBuild 4 Property Function

```
<Target Name="Regex">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <In>agent0076</In>
    <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), `[1-9]\d*`))</Out>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="Input : $(In) Output : $(Out)"/>
  <!-- Input : agent0076 Output : 76 -->
</Target>
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine with MSBuild 4. But with MSBuild 3.5 I get the output : , '[1-9]\d*'))

Answer (score -5):

The regex is very simple `\d+`. Once you have the string that matches that, you can use `int.Parse` to extract the value.